# Can I automatically transfer content from a static site to wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, import

I have a static website with recipes. I would like to copy my recipes to WordPress without having to do it manually (Ctrl + V, Ctrl + C).

When I put the recipe (posts) in Wordpress, looks like the picture.

[image: Posts]

I would like to put information into the red highlighted fields from my static page. The problem is to put different information from my static page, into different forms for posts.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 or 2 recipes

then go to tools export, export the file for wordpress,

Open the file in an editor, 
copy and paste the 1/2 posts, for each recipe,
enter all the info for all posts...

then re-import your file, this should create all your posts for you.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to write a script or small application to parse out the content from your source and insert it into the WordPress database (or autofill the fields).  It is unlikely someone has written that for this particular situation.